# When not to use View Services in MVVM design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm

I'm using the MVVM design pattern in my application which is comprised of,

- A Xamarin.IOs project (View Layer)
- A Net Standard project (Common Layer)
- A Xamarin.Android project (in the future) (View Layer)

In the Xamarin.IOs project, there's a Delegate class (`NotificationCenterDelegate` extending `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`) which triggers a method (`WillPresentNotification`) on receiving a notification. This method should inform a ViewModel (`BasePageViewModel`) that the method was invoked. The `BasePageViewModel` is not injected to the Delegate class.

There's a couple of approaches I can use here,

1. Inject a ViewModel (`ControlViewModel`). Then invoke a method in the ViewModel from the `WillPresentNotification` method.

   ```
   public void WillPresentNotification(/* parameters */)
   {
       ControlViewModel.UpdateCount();
   }
   ```

   In `ControlViewModel` I invoke an event that is captured and handled in `BasePageViewModel`
2. Implement an Interface (`IDelegateViewService`) in the Delegate class that has an Event Handler. Trigger the event in the `WillPresentNotification` method.

   ```
   public class NotificationCenterDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, INotificationCenterDelegate
   {
       public void WillPresentNotification(/* parameters */)
       {
           CountUpdated?.Invoke(this, null);
       }
   }

   public interface IDelegateViewService
   {
       event EventHandler CountUpdated;
   }
   ```

   Then capture handle the event in the `BasePageViewModel`.

I prefer the first approach as it doesn't use an interface to invoke something in the ViewModel. Because as I feel using ViewServices reduces the ability of sharing code among different platforms. And I feel ViewServices should be only used if it's the only approach available.

Can anyone comment on these two design approaches? I would like to get some theory involving why one is better than the other or why a completely different design is much better!